# boost signals2 duplicate variable name

Tags: c++, boost

I have two classes A and B with both classes having a boost signal named SigCompleted.

```
boost::signals2::signal<void ()> SigCompleted;
```

Is it a problem to have the same signal name in two different classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that should not be a problem.

A signal is just like any regular member variable. Having the same member variable name in different classes is perfectly possible. There's nothing unusual about signals in this regard.

For example

```
A a;
B b;
a.SigCompleted.connect(&someFunctionThatReactsToASendingTheCompletedSignal);
b.SigCompleted.connect(&someFunctionThatReactsToBSendingTheCompletedSignal);
```

works just fine.

Actually, depending on the situation, it may be very natural to use the same signal name in different classes.